# gspread - Google project boots client email share and removes org access restrictions after python gspread update

Tags: python, gspread

I have set up an automated python process that periodically updates google spreadsheets with sensitive data. It is extremely important that these spreadsheets remain restricted to users/emails with which I have shared the spreadsheets.

I have been following the documentation here:
https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#enable-api-access

I am able to restrict access to the spreadsheet, share the spreadsheet with the client email in the project credentials I have created and desired users, and successfully update the spreadsheet via python. However, not long after the spreadsheet has been updated, the client email is booted from the share, and the access restriction is reverted to being available to everyone within my organization. Further confusing the matter is that it says my email address is responsible for making both of those changes, even though I never have! I have also requested that my organization whitelist the client email domain, but this has not changed anything.

This only seems to happen after the spreadsheet is updated via the python process. The first few times I had remained logged in to my google drive and had the spreadsheets open in my browser, occurring ~20 minutes following the successful update. On the most recent occasion, I logged out of my google account prior to kicking off the python process, and this time the issue occurred just 3 minutes after the sheets were updated.

Has anyone run into this before or know how to solve this issue?

Thank you,

Sumanth